# Overloading a Qt-function in a sub-class of QTcpServer

Tags: c++, qt, overloading

I have a subclass of [QTcpServer](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qtcpserver.html):

.h-file:

```
#ifndef GEOLISTENER_H
#define GEOLISTENER_H

#include <QTcpServer>

class GeoListener : public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GeoListener(QObject *parent = 0);
    bool listen(void);
signals:

public slots:
    void handleConnection(void);

};

#endif // GEOLISTENER_H
```

.cpp-file:

```
#include "geolistener.h"
#include <QDebug>

GeoListener::GeoListener(QObject *parent) :
    QTcpServer(parent)
{
    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(newConnection()),this, SLOT(handleConnection()));
}

bool GeoListener::listen(void)
{
    bool ret;
    ret = this->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 9871); //This function isn't found!
    /* If something is to be done right after listen starts */

    return ret;
}

void GeoListener::handleConnection(void) {
    qDebug() << "got connection";
}
```

The base class of the Qt-Framework has this function:

```
bool QTcpServer::listen ( const QHostAddress & address = QHostAddress::Any, quint16 port = 0 )
```

I overloaded it with a listen()-function. If I do that I can't call the function above - in my opinion this should work. Why isn't it working? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, just a remark: those QT classes are designed for composition, not for inheritance.

Anyway, the problem here is that your `listen()` function is hiding the base's `listen()`.

Your problem is resolved by:

```
static_cast<QTcpServer*>(this)->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 9871);
```

Comment: I primely do it by inheritance to refresh my skills - it's just a project for the university.

So do I understand you right that there is a listen()-function in the base-class which isn't in the documentation? I just don't understand why the listen()-function overwrites the  listen ( const QHostAddress & address = QHostAddress::Any, quint16 port = 0 )-function. They have totally different parameters.

Comment: No, it's exactly the function with the signature `listen(const QHostAddress&, quint)` that you are hiding. This 'feature' of C++ is described in the standard (ref $3.3.10).

Answer (score 1):

Because the name `listen` hides the base's function with the same name. In the definition of your class you can write
`using QTcpServer::listen;` and thus the base's listen will be able to participate in overload resolution